# Jest test fails, working fine on original file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a script that dedupes a csv file provided.

My intention is to make a global module package that can be globaly installed and run on the command line, it will log out if there are duplicates or not.

It works well when using the `ts-node` directly on the file.
But I do not know how to test when it succeeds and logs out something.

This is the sctructure and the relevant files

```
|— __tests__
  |— index.test.ts
  |— data.csv
|— lib
|— src
  |— index.ts
  |— data.csv
tsconfig.json
node_modules
tslint.json
jest.config.js
```

The index.ts works fine

```
import csv from 'csv-parser'
import { createReadStream } from 'fs'
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises'
import { Parser } from 'json2csv'
import { resolve } from 'path'
import chalk from 'chalk'
const { cyan, yellow, green } = chalk

const writeCSV = async (dest: string, data: any[]) => {
  const fields = Object.keys(data[0])
  const opts = { fields }

  try {
    const parser = new Parser(opts)
    const csv = parser.parse(data)
    await writeFile(dest, csv)
  } catch (err) {
    throw new ReferenceError(err)
  }
}

export const Deduper = async (column: string, file: string) => {
  const json = []
  const unique = new Set()
  let counter = 0

  console.log(cyan('Working...'))

  const filePath = resolve(__dirname, file) // Resolve the absolute file path

  createReadStream(filePath)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('error', (error) => console.log(error))
    .on('data', (data) => {
      if (!unique.has(data[column])) {
        unique.add(data[column])
        json.push(data)
      } else {
        counter++
      }
    })
    .on('end', async () => {
      if (counter > 0) {
        const plural = counter > 1 ? 's' : ''
        await writeCSV(`${file.split('.csv')[0]}_dedupped.csv`, json)
        console.log(yellow.bold(`${counter.toString()} duplicate${plural} found`))
      } else {
        console.log(green.bold('No duplicates found'))
      }
    })
}

// Read command-line arguments and call Deduper
;(async () => await Deduper(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]))()
```

If I run

```
ts-node ./src/index.ts 'Column' 'data.csv'
```

It all works fine and I get the expected results.

However If I run a test on this with

`index.test.ts`

```
import { Deduper } from '../src/index'

describe('Deduper', () => {
  // Spy on the console.log method
  beforeEach(() => jest.spyOn(console, 'log'))
  // Restore the original console.log method
  afterEach(() => jest.restoreAllMocks())

  it('should log "1 duplicate found"', async () => {
    await Deduper('Column', 'data.csv')

    // Assert that console.log was called with the expected message
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('1 duplicate found')
  })
})
```

I get this error `TypeError: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined`.

Mainly the Deduper function gets no parameters from the `index.test.ts`

Comment: if you remove the mocks, does it get the argument? Is it possible that you have test pollution from another file?

Comment: No, same thing, undefined

Comment: The posted code looks good. I would drop this into a debugger to test it out

Comment: I can not even make a simple test with Jest, so not sure what is going to work on the debugger which I have never used. I just run the debugger on vscode and basically errors out in the same way

Comment: I would want to look at the call stack. Are both args null? or a single arg? Using a debugger, you can also check if deduper is mocked somehow accidentally. Using a debugger is a good skill to have for troubleshooting stuff like this

Comment: Both parameters are undefined, it seems that Jest is unable to test this script that works from the command line and logs things out

Comment: Remove the line reading from cli args.

Comment: @morganney But I want to be able to use this from the commad line, and even removing that line would not fixed it, still errors out

Comment: @morganney ●  Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?